# MSI: An Application is running during silent update

Tags: windows, installation, wix, windows-installer

I have an application that was installed as MSI package, I have next version of application that I plan to install in silent mode by special program.

When application is running I catch an issue: not all components of application installed 
immediately, some of them will be really ready only after reboot. And I get unstable application.

I can check - is application running and wait until it closed, but I can't check the situation when user click on shortcut during silent installation.

How I can avoid this? Can I lock application during installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest implementing [Restart Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373524%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) support. Vista or later will attempt to shut down your application via the Restart Manager, you can decide how to handle it within your application (prompt user, autosave, something else, etc).

You won't catch the situation where the user starts the application during update, but it will handle multi-user sessions more gracefully than your custom code will.

Comment: I am looking for universal solution including XP and I suppose that users restart their computers once in 2-3 months, but I will check RegisterApplicationRestart function

Comment: For XP you can probably do something like set a registry key and clear it on boot (e.g. runonce) and then have your application prevent itself from starting if the registry key is present + instruct the user to reboot.